# OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFE1CD34660 (or generic address) when multi-threading an FMU in Python

Tags: interface, functional-programming, mockups

I have a question regarding using the parameter_variation.py script provided on GitHub.

I'm using FMPy functions here (https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy) and have a specific error occurring only when I run a certain FMU, which is only slightly different from other FMU’s I’ve been using with a modified version of the parameter_variation.py example script provided.

Errors:

```
...    
File "c:\parameter_variation.py", line 136, in simulate_fmu
    fmu.terminate()    
File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fmpy\fmi2.py", line 231, in terminate
   return self.fmi2Terminate(self.component)    
File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fmpy\fmi2.py", line 169, in w res = f(*args, **kwargs)    
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFE1CD34660    
End
```

I’m running 100 simulations for this FMU in 20 chunks, although the same FMU in the parameter_variation.py script appears to provide results if I run less than ~30 simulations in ~6 chunks.

Do you have any guesses why the access violation error may be occurring and how a solution can be forged? Let me know if this is enough information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the question should be reformulated to articulate the problem in a more generalized way without mentioning a concrete address. Obviously the address may differ from system to system and even from run to run.

Comment: @AndreySScherbakov Thanks for the tip, Andrey. Made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

In the title you mention *multi-threading* (multiple instances of the same FMU in the same process) which is not supported by many FMUs and can lead to unexpected side effects (e.g. through access to shared resources). If this is the case here you should be able to run your variation with a synchronized scheduler by setting the variable `sync = True` in [parameter_variation.py (line 27)](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/blob/ff1c6cec0f2c2dc13c5743f1d24206be20e56d9c/fmpy/examples/parameter_variation.py#L27).